# Error code -1011 when I use AFNetWorking

Tags: iphone, error-code, afnetworking

I am doing a service in our customer company. And I try to get some information from their server by AFNetWorking (Our customer encourage to use AFNetWorking)
I did some sample using AFNetWorking, and it's work.
But when I use one of our customer URLs to get JSON data, it failed and this is error description:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 
"Expected status code <NSIndexSet: 0x7e274f0>[number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), 
indexes: (200-299)], got 403" UserInfo=0x7b64040 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=<url_hidden_for_stackoverflow>, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code <NSIndexSet: 0x7e274f0>[number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 403}
```

I try to find out some solution, but I can't fix yet. There's my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
//[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/json"];
//NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:CONST_KEY_REGISTER_UNIQUE_KEY, CONST_API_KEY_TEXT,nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"path/to/page.json" parameters:nil];
[httpClient release];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSString *status = [JSON valueForKey:@"status"];
    if ([status isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
        NSString *uniqueId = [JSON valueForKey:@"uniqueId"];
        [UserSettings setWithKey:CONST_PROGRAM_UNIQUE_KEY value:uniqueId];
    }
    //NSString *message = [json valueForKey:@"message"];
    //NSString *error = [json valueForKey:@"error"];
    [[LoadingView instance] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeLoadingView)  withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *errorString = [error description];
    [[LoadingView instance] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeLoadingView)  withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

Thanks for reading, and any help or reply will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As DarkDust said: server deny my access. But I can get data from server by basic connection:
Here is code to get:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/path/to/page.json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:CONST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT];
rssConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadStarted) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
if (rssConnection != nil) {
    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    } while (!done);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // I can get text here, but it is not JSON format
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
}
```

I wonder why rssConnection can get JSON text and AFHTTPClient can not ?

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to post internal/private details of your customer without obfuscation?

Comment: This is just a test page, not private page. There will be more change before I can finish. And future, there will need API key to access, and of course, I hide it

Comment: Still, everybody now can see who your customer is. Your customer might not be very happy about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is responding with the HTTP error code 403 which means *Forbidden*. It denies you access. You need to find out why, for example by reading the server logs (if you can) or asking the server administrator to help you. It might be access restrictions on the server that need to be lifted/modified.

**Edit**: A HTTP `POST` is an operation that wants to save something on the server. While the normal `GET` seems to work just fine according to your edited question, saving is prohibited right now. First thing to do is still examine the server configuration. Additionally, if your URL points to a script (JSP, ASP, whatever) which is the only thing that would make sense in your case you need to examine that to determine why it denies you access (if the server configuration doesn't already deny it, it must be the script).

Comment: The error message you've posted clearly says `Expected status code ..., got 403`. The server is denying you access.

Comment: I edit my post, because If i add comment, I can't tell you clearly what I need to.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question is closed. Our customer use this server for testing and give me wrong configuration. I can connect the test server by "GET" method. The test page is just text/plain and not JSON format at all.

Answer (score 25):

As reference because of high search result via google...

For others that are looking for the possible error codes retrieved via AFNetworking, consult the apple documentation for [URL Loading System Error Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes) as these are the same.

NSURLErrorBadServerResponse = -1011

Returned when the URL Loading system receives bad data from the server.
This is equivalent to the “500 Server Error” message sent by HTTP servers.