# AFNetworking file upload fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, file-upload, afnetworking

Hi I am using following code for uploading image on server

```
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://test.com/upload_test/" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataToPost
                                    name:@"attachment"
                                fileName:@"myimage.png"
                                mimeType:@"image/png"];
    } error:nil];


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
    [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                         NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
                                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                     }];


    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Wrote %lld/%lld", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];


    [operation start];
```

and I am getting the following error

```
Failure Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0xc0428a0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xaa389e0> { URL: http://test.com/upload_test/ } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 210;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    Date = "Fri, 05 Sep 2014 07:32:49 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://test.com/upload_test/, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)
```

**I have tried on one another server on which control reaches to success block But no file is uploaded to the server.**

**What are the server configuration or permission required for file upload ?**

I am working on iOS 7.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234186/afnetworking-uploading-a-file

Comment: @Ganesh I have already tried that link.

Comment: name:@"attachment"
                                fileName:@"myimage.png"
                                mimeType:@"image/png"  for this parameters does server needs to create these or it is by default property

Comment: can u take a look in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228903/uploading-image-with-afnetworking-with-null-parameter-doesnt-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your server base url"]];
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[manager POST:@"url to upload image" parameters:@"parameter required by the server" constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure %@, %@", error, operation.responseString);
}];
```

Its Working for me. I hope it helps

Comment: I will try it and will let you know.

Comment: I get the following error using above code

Failure Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo=0xaea3bf0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse:
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /upload_test/
on this server.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: what parameters do i need to send ??  any other server configuration required ??

Comment: i think your api needs some token or authentication to access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991927/error-code-1011-when-i-use-afnetworking

Comment: I am looking at the link provided but did you used any php or any other script to upload the file ??
i am using your code like this 
Your server base url: http://server11.com
url to upload image : /upload_test

Comment: yeah i used php script but it was done by web personal, i used a token to access the api

Comment: Where did you gave the refrence of the php script in native objective c code.  Can u share the php script if possible ?

Comment: well i don't have the script but i think the problem is from web side as you don't have access on upload_test folder in the server

Comment: Where did you gave the reference of the php script in native objective c code for file upload ??

Comment: Thanks a lot , I am able to upload image successfully after using the self created php script but not able to upload video file of size (3MB).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61483/discussion-between-dinesh-kaushik-and-xphobia).

Comment: name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png" for this parameters does server needs to create these or it is by default property

Comment: can u take a look in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228903/uploading-image-with-afnetworking-with-null-parameter-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

This error is from the API where we send data with HTTP code, So please in the API code that if they are sending data then there always the http code should be 200