# AF Networking Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:serverUrl parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"post_media" fileName:imageName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[requestDict objectForKey:@"user_statusmessage"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"user_statusmessage"];

    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[requestDict objectForKey:@"user_description"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"user_description"];

    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[requestDict objectForKey:@"id"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]   name:@"id"];


    [request addValue:self.header forHTTPHeaderField: @"X-API-KEY"];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSProgress *progress = nil;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

and the error is

Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo=0x181643d0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://myrequesturl.net/folder } { status code: 403, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 63;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 13 Aug 2015 06:48:49 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.27";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://erpdemo.net/battalionsREST-Server/Usermanager_api/updateprofile, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403),

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error code -1011 when I use AFNetWorking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991927/error-code-1011-when-i-use-afnetworking)

Comment: I figured out the issue , it regarding the header. The X-API-KEY is not properly assigned.  can anybody tell me how to do this  ?

Answer (score 0):

In your **AFHTTPClient** example you are setting the default encoding to AFJSONParameterEncoding, by default AFHTTPRequestOperationManager uses **AFHTTPRequestSerializer** so you need set the **requestSerializer**.

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: you got a 400 response from the server, meaning that what you sent was either not formatted properly, or the server just couldn't understand it.
Refer the following link that may help you:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1729